# Can't remove the bullets form bootstrap calendar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[image]

Can't remove those bullet from bootstrap datepicker. Help me. it's looking very ugly.

here is the link: http://hmodels.co.nf/frontend/student_admit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On **`index.css:64`**

```
ul li {
    background: url('bullet.gif') no-repeat scroll 20px 8px transparent;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

This is what make the bullet, as the calendar use `<ul> <li>`.

I don't know why you use this CSS, so, add this if you just want to disable it for the date-picker

```
.datepicker-panel ul li {
    background-image: none;
}
```